# exporting blender models into opengl as obj

Tags: opengl, glut, blender

I have a simple .obj loader in my project, it works i loaded some obj files i was given.
Now i want to load ones i made myself, i looked on the internet and it said to make one in blender, then export it as obj, with these function selected: Include Normals, Include UVs, Triangulate Faces.
However i do not have the option to Include Normals in my blender, all i have is Write Normals.
When i select them and export the model into obj, it just crashes when i try to run it saying "Expression: vector subscript out of range".
Can someone tell me how to export .blend models into .obj so opengl can see them? i am using freeglut.

Comment: Investigate in your loader, check parsing steps with a simple cube made in blender.

Answer (score -2):

Selection only
apply modifiers
include edges
wrrite normal
include uvs
write materials
triangulate faces
objects as obj objects

these are the correct selections for anyone that wonders.

Comment: Without any formatting, capitalization or punctuation, this answer is unreadable gibberish.